# About language-specific versions of math.stackexchange

Tags: feature-request, languages

It is a widespread issue in many communities to have a very bad attitude towards the English language. Despite this being a true handicap during the information age, many students, even researchers, still refuse to learn and use something different from their mother tongue. I am thinking of **many** Chinese, Russian, Japanese, German, French and Italian people.

I think it would be great to have language-specific versions of the stackexchange community sites (especially *math*) to attract more people and increase the opportunities of cooperation. With a sort of automatic translator, why not.

Will this ever happen?

Comment: Localized version have been proposed/suggester for SO: See http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ and also http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54232/stack-overflow-in-german or http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-english

Comment: I've no idea about Russian. However, for Chinese and Japanese, there should not be any real problem to ask them to post in English.

Comment: I live in China. My work colleagues are a highly educated bunch -- about 50% of them have masters degrees in technical fields. The official language of our company is English, but there are many people who can not use it effectively. So, I have to disagree with Achille. I think the language barrier is significant for many Chinese students. Maybe there is a site similar to MSE in Chinese. Does anyone know? After all, the internet now contains more Chinese material than English.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Can’t We All be Reasonable and Speak English?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/) is the tongue-in-cheek title of the announcement of
[Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), "é um site de perguntas e respostas para programadores profissionais e entusiastas". It launched in February and is doing well as far as I can tell, despite early worries about fragmentation of knowledge base. From the announcement:

> So know this: we are at least as worried about fragmentation as you are. And we have a plan:
>
> **Eventually, *all of you* are going to have to learn Portuguese.**

An obvious prerequisite for the existence of an SE site in a language other than English: Stack Exchange must have a Community Manager fluent in the language. For the Portuguese site they hired [Gabe, The Smiling Community Manager](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/08/introducing-gabe-the-smiling-community-manager/). They recently added [jmac, Community Manager of the Rising Sun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/07/please-welcome-jmac-community-manager-of-the-rising-sun/) and are still looking for two bilingual CMs:   English/Japanese and English/Spanish.

As Jonas Meyer said, there are proposals for Math in Korean and in Spanish. Given that SE wants to add a Spanish-speaking CM already, it seems that the Spanish language proposal has a better chance of becoming reality soon. So far, its  level of support on Area51 remains low (but it might increase if Stack Overflow in Spanish is created).

> It's easy to identify areas that need a SE site, quite another to actually gather the right people into *creating* a site. -- [Shog9](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=2275134#2275134)

Answer (score 7):

[Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is where new Stack Exchange sites can be proposed.  That is how this site began.  There are currently two proposals for Mathematics-in-another-language sites, [one in Korean](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/72072/mathematics-in-korean) and [one in Spanish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64529/matematicas-mathematics-se-in-spanish).  You could add another proposal or support these ones.

I don't know if it will ever happen, but it <s>will</s> might if the proposals get enough support on Area 51.  (Edit: 900sit-ups adds that practicality also depends on whether Community Managers fluent in the relevant languages are hired.)